# How do you unit test web page authorization using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd

Let's say you have a profile page that can only be accessed by the owner of that profile.  This profile page is located at:

User/Profile/{userID}

Now, I imagine in order to prevent access to this page by other users, you could structure your UserController class's Profile function to check the current session's identity:

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

If the id matches the one in the url, then you proceed.  Otherwise you redirect to some sort of error page.

My question is how do you unit test something like this?  I'm guessing that you need to use some sort of dependency injection instead of the HttpContext in the controller to do the check on, but I am unclear what the best way to do that is.  Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the "UserNameFilter" shown in Kazi Manzur's [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx).  Works like a charm and easy to unit test.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it by using a fake for the controller context. Check out this article: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/01/asp-net-mvc-tip-12-faking-the-controller-context.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The link above is a good one. I would also add that instead of programmatically checking the User.Identity.Name value, you should use the Authorize attributes as outlined in the article:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is where mocking comes in, with a fake HttpContext.